# Use ES6 library's ES5 module without compiling it on my own project with rollup

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, rollup, luxon

I need to use an ES6 library *(Luxon)* and want to compile down the files to ES5, but Rollup adds the files as ES6.

The library has a special `/build` folder with different output formats.

How can I configure Rollup to make use of that instead of doing nothing with the library?

Comment: Could you explain that clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have two options here:

- Either compiling the library on your project with Rollup and
  [@rollup/plugin-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-babel)
- Or referencing the `/build` directory of the package instead of the ES6
  version of the package, using an alias with [@rollup/plugin-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-alias)

I'll go with the second approach because is the one you asked for:

1. Install the plugin `npm i @rollup/plugin-alias`
2. At `rollup.config.js` import it `import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';`
3. Finally, add it to `plugins`:

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'output',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  plugins: [
    alias({
      entries: [
        { find: 'luxon', replacement: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/luxon/build') },

      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: This solution wasn't initially working for me. Turns out if you're using the `@rollup/plugin-commonjs` and/or `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`, you need to load those after the alias plugin. Otherwise the entry will be handled by them before getting to the alias plugin.